# Is there any way to increase the upload speed of Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm setting up a Plex server on my Google Cloud Platform instance, but media files are stalling since the Google Cloud upload rate does not exceed the 10 mbps mark. I live in Timon, Maranhão and the nearest Google server is in São Paulo in Brazil, the download rate reaches 1Gbps and the lenght is 60ms, plus the upload is only 10mbps .. Using the Speedtest.net site for the speed test. Could someone help me to improve the upload speed?

Comment: This is not a question for nor a problem with Google Cloud. Contact your Internet provider to negotiate faster upload speeds.

Comment: I'm saying that the speed of VM Upload is 10mbps .. my internet provider's speed is 100mbps for download and 80 for upload ... more I want to create my server in GCP and be able to access from my home, more Upload is too low making it impossible to watch without crashing

Comment: The upload speed for a Google Cloud VM is 2 Gbit per CPU core. Your limitation is outside of Google's network. Your limitation is an issue from your home / office to your Internet provider to the nearest Google network access point. Also note even if your Internet provider states 80 Mbit upload speed you will NOT get that on one connection. Typically you will achieve stated upload speeds over the sum of several connections and only for periods of time.

Comment: My internet connection is very good, both for upload and download ... The upload speed in cities closer to the server is faster. Yes, the server is located in São Paulo, in the South of Brazil and I live in Timon, in the north of brazil .. plus the download rate is the same, however the Upload is only 10mbps ... the Download is 1Gbps in the VM ..

"The upload speed for Google Cloud VM is 2 Gbit per CPUcore."This in theory, in practice only increases a few mbits. could you help me? check it out via TeamViewer or something like that. I've been there for 2 weeks and I can not solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I think that the limitation is not on Google side since Google Cloud Platform does not impose bandwidth caps for ingress traffic, the amount of ingress traffic a GCE instance can handle, depends on the machine type and [operating system](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_instance).

On the other hand, the outbound or egress traffic from a virtual machine is subject to maximum network egress throughput caps. These caps are dependent on the number of vCPUs that a virtual machine instance has. Each core is subject to a 2 Gbits/second (Gbps) cap for peak performance. Each additional core increases the network cap, up to a theoretical maximum of 16 Gbps for each [virtual machine](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/advanced-vpc#measurenetworkthroughput).

You can see this yourself by setting up a bunch of [instance types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types), and logging their [IPerf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf) performance. As @John Hanley states Google does not have any guarantees for performance via the Internet, since upload speeds can vary based on a number of conditions, including the ISP that is using from on-premises.

Comment: it is a theory. in practice. I used to upload files to VMs on GCP with at least 20mbps speed (from UK) and now it is 600-700kbps. Max upload link to my ISP is 50mbps. These uploads are happening using ssh-in-browser. and I think Google did something to it because it feels different from what it was couple years ago

Answer (score 1):

One of the (many) limits to the performance of a TCP connection is:

Throughput <= WindowSize / RoundTripTime

So it is possible that the window size your local system and the instance in GCP will provide in the upload direction needs to be increased to accommodate the round-trip-time between the two.  What do you see for the RoundTripTime?  For example, if you "ping" your instance from your local system what does it say about the round-trip-time?

Also, it is not enough for the receiver to advertise that much window, the sender must be willing/able to send that much.  So, both sides may need to be tweaked.

Further, there has been a change in the computation of the per-VM network egress cap since Raul's answer.  It is still computed as 2 Gbit/s multiplied by the number of vCPUs in the instance, but the upper bound (if you specify Skylake or better for the CPU family) is now 32 Gbit/s, and there is now a lower bound of 10 Gbit/s for instances with 2 or more vCPUs.  That cap is applied to the VM as as whole.  As before, those are "guaranteed not to exceed" *not* "guaranteed to achieve."

Comment: for more details https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types?hl=en_GB#general_purpose

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

Alternatively, you can upload files in google storage. Then `ssh` to the server and download the file `gcloud storage cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME SAVE_TO_LOCATION`

Optionally, you can zip those files before uploading to google cloud storage

gcloud storage CLI:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#cli-download-object